# how big is largest side of triangle compared to other side

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Let $T$ be a triangle with vertex $A$, $B$ and $C$ and sides lengths $a$, $b$ and $c$ opposite to their vertex. We have $c\geq b\geq a$. Consider a line segment joining midpoint of $AB$ with $C$. Let the midpoint be $L$ and length of $CL$ be $l$. Can we have an lower-bound $\alpha>0$ on $c-l$ i.e. $c-l \geq \alpha$ ?

I tried applying triangle inequality. We have $a+\frac{c}{2}> l $ which in turn implies $c-l>\frac{c}{2}-a$. However if $a \geq \frac{c}{2}$ this result is obvious. We also have $b>l$. Thus, $c-l >c-b$. If $c=b$ then again $\alpha=0$. I want an $\alpha >0$.

Comment: Your $\alpha$ is a lowerbound, not an upperbound.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: I think I can prove that $c-l\geq\left(1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove that
$$c-l\geq\left(1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)c$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}c\geq\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}$$ or
$$3c^2\geq2a^2+2b^2-c^2$$ or
$$2c^2-a^2-b^2\geq0.$$ 
The equality occurs for $a=b=c$,

which says that $1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ is a maximal value of $k$ for which the inequality
$$c-l\geq kc$$
is true for all triangle whith $c\geq b\geq c$.

By the way, for $c\rightarrow0^+$ in $c-l\geq\alpha$ we obtain $0\geq\alpha$, which gives $\alpha=0$ is a maximal $\alpha$,

for which your inequality is true.

Comment: Can you elaborate you procedure a bit more. We have $2c^2 \geq a^2+b^2$. If we try to replace $a$ and $b$ in terms of $c$ and $l$ using triangle inequality, we get a quadratic in $c$ and $l$. I can't reduce it from that form to your form.

Comment: @user402940 If you want that I'll prove that $c-l\geq\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)c$?

Comment: That will be a great help.

Comment: @user402940 I added something.

Comment: @user402940 It was a typo. I fixed. I used $l=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}$. Is this clear or it needs a proof?

Comment: It is clear now. Thanks. I removed my comment.

Comment: @user402940 You are welcome!